# Keep $_GET value of a drop down menu after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**EDITED:**

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/53GKh/6/

I have 2 Drop down menu's in HTML:

First one is to get car brand:(is working fine)

```
<form action="car-list.php" method="get">
<select name="search" id="main_list" >
<option value="BMW"<?php if ($_GET['search']== 'BMW') {echo "selected='selected'"; }   ?>>Bmw</option>
</select>
</form>
```

After the user choose a Brand the second drop down menu will be 'activated' to choose the model of the car:

```
<select  name="model"  id="brand" class="secondary">
<option disabled selected> Kies </option>
</select>
```

To 'activate' the second drop down menu im using the following JS code:

```
$(function() {
var sel, i,
    list = ['aixman', 'alfaromeo', 'bmw'],
    aixman = ['Aixman'],
    alfaromeo = ['33', '75'],
    bmw= ['1-serie','3-serie','4-serie','5-serie','6-serie'],
    astonmartin = ['Cygnet', 'DB7'],

    dev_default = '<option value="default" selected>Kies</option>',



sel_brand = $('#brand');
sel_version = $('#version');

$('select').change(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'main_list':
            sel_brand.find('option').remove();
            sel_brand.append(dev_default);
            sel_brand.show();
            if (this.value == 'BMW') {
                for (i = 0; i < bmw.length; i++) {
                    $("#brand").append(
                        '<option value="' + bmw[i] + '">' + bmw[i] + '</option>'
                    );        
                }

            }
            break;

    }
});

}); //END document.ready()
```

I have just updated my JS code: How can I echo the selected value of my second dropbox menu after submitting/refreshing the page?

Comment: Assuming that the form submit refreshes your page, you will have to reinitiate the ajax call to get and set the options for the second dropdown. You may do so by changing  $('#merk').change(function(e) {..................}).trigger("change");

Comment: thanks, but it dose not work..

Comment: when we'll post a comment, we mean something. Did you at least clarify my assumption? It's very easy to just pop in and say "doesn't work"! Can you define "doesn't work". Please bear in mind we are not here to do your homework.

Comment: I did what you told me in the comment, and it dose not worked...
When i put .trigger("change"); at the end of mu code the drop down menu freeze and I'm not even able to choose from the first dropdown menu.. BTW, I didn't ask anyone to to my homework, I'm just asking for help.

Comment: Please start to correct basic errors, such as, change option(value="0") to option[value="0"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change your server-side PHP code to accommodate this functionality.

Steps:

1. Whenever a form is submitted, using the menu 1 selection, get all the values for menu 2 and set in a variable.
2. In the HTML of second menu, you check that if the variable in step 1 [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset), and if yes, then create HTML for the options of menu 2 in a loop. Also, while doing so, using the selected value from your form submission, pre-select the option. Else if [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), then do nothing.

When the user will be making a selection in menu 1, JavaScript will kick in and do its task. And whenever form is submitted, this will pre-create the menu 2.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction. Kindly ask if you face any difficulty in implementing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for youre comment!
I've just editted my JS code and second drop down menu is working fine, Now I need to keep my selected value in the second dropdown menu after refreshing/submitting the form.I just don't know how to do it in js

Comment: That sounds good. For next task, I suggest passing the selected value (if any, or null otherwise) from PHP to a JavaScript variable. While creating the second dropdown in a loop, check if the value of option matches that value. If it does, then print 'selected="selected"' in it.